# Invalid schema element named "notnull" at path "JobeetCategory->columns->name"

Tags: symfony1, model, doctrine, jobeet

I am running Symphony 1.4 and on the following tutorial:
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03.

However when I run './symfony doctrine:build --model' i get the error:

> Invalid schema element named "notnull" at path "JobeetCategory->columns->name"

Can someone please help...

The scheme looks like this:

```
JobeetCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
```

Comment: Please provide your whole schema file. And be aware always use 2 spaces (not more, not less, noting else).

Comment: hi scube, the above is the whole schema file. I deleted all the other schema settings to narrow down the fault. @scube

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code works for me. But try that:

```
JobeetCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  indexes:
    unique_fields:       { type: unique, fields: [name] }
```

Comment: I tried the above code but got the following output:             
 `Invalid schema element named "notnull" at path "JobeetCategory->columns->name"` @scube